# not inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason my post value of the bookingDate is not getting put into the database and I"m not sure why.

Inside the console here's the post variables.
    bookingDate     04/25/2012 14:36

inside the database 
    bookingDate  datetime

```
/**
 * Book Event
 *
 * @param   string
 * @param   integer
 * @param   date
 * @param   string
 * @param   string
 * @param   text
 * @return  bool
 */
function bookEvent($eventName, $label, $bookingDate, $location, $arena, $introduction)
{       
    $data = array(
        'eventsNamesListID' => $eventName,
        'label' => $label,
        'bookingDate' => $bookingDate,
        'location' => $location,
        'eventsArenasListID' => $arena,
        'eventsStatusesID' => 1,
        'introduction' => $introduction
    );

    $this->db->insert('events', $data);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How would we know? You appear to be using your own database class, so we don't even know what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: If u notice I included codeignitor in the tags.

Comment: Uh, **no you didn't**. The tags on this post are `php` and `mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah... and what about a proper datetime 2012-04-25 14:36:00 ?

Comment: What function do I use to convert it into a proper one?

Answer (score -1):

Is `$bookingDate` initialized when you pass it into the function?

You'll need to manually assign the `$_POST['bookingDate']` to the variable `$bookingDate` with a line like this prior to calling your `bookEvent()` function.

`$bookingDate = $_POST['bookingDate'];`

In any case you should `echo $bookingDate;` prior to calling your function so that we can verify that `$bookingDate` is holding the value you expect it to be for your database insert.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling this function?  It would also help to see the code of your database class.

Comment: I think I just need to reformat the date and time. Thank you though.